# What is the most rapid way to use docker to test X applications with linux distribution docker images?

Tags: docker, testing

I want to use docker to demonstrate an issue with an X application package in a distribution (in this example, Fedora, and the package is gnofract4d).

The requirement is to do something like 'docker run feodora:32', and then interact with that container to enable a 'clean' test of an X application with a specific release of Fedora. The goal is to allow other developers and testers to easily and rigorously reproduce the issue and be able to observe and debug the system.

Obviously, this makes existing docker images with elaborate Dockerfiles for running X applications inadmissible -- the whole point is to show how a package works or fails to work in a 'stock' distribution image.

I have googled around but haven't found anything that is straightforward ... I'm going to continue testing with some thoughts I have.

Anyone with a simple solution to this problem?

Comment: If your requirements are "Linux distribution" and "graphical application with X server", a virtual machine will be a much closer match to a "normal" desktop installation.

Comment: David Maze - agreed ... but I was looking for something more rapid and lower overhead. Someone can always download and then spin up a distribution VM image; however, my answer below takes about 5 minutes, start to finish, with no need to configure or specify VM details (memory, CPU, disk, etc). For some cases a VM is the only option, I admit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I am answering my own question, I have found a fairly straightforward approach to this problem. I am posting the answer right away, because I think seeing the answer to this question will go a long way towards helping people understand what I am asking. [I'm still interested in other approaches to this issue, however.]

Based on the constraints of the question, the following overall docker flow is working for me:

1) Start a container representing a distribution in a fundamental 'clean' state (stock fedora:32, in this example), install Xvfb and any other application prereqs, install an rpm for an X application package via url, and finally use Xvfb to run the application in X:

```
docker run --name=fedora_test_container fedora:32 /bin/bash -c "dnf -y install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb gtk3 ; dnf -y install https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org/packages/gnofract4d/4.1/2.fc32/x86_64/gnofract4d-4.1-2.fc32.x86_64.rpm ; xvfb-run gnofract4d"
```

2) Assume that the command was successful and the app you started (in this case, gnofract4d) is running. To interact with it for further testing, we can install x11vnc in the container to access the Xvfb session. From a 2nd terminal:

```
docker exec fedora_test_container dnf -y install x11vnc
docker exec fedora_test_container x11vnc -safer -once -nopw -auth $(ls -d /tmp/xvfb*/*) -ncache_cr -geometry 640x480 -display :99
```

3) Lastly, from a 3rd terminal, run vncviewer (previously installed on your host system) to view the app in the container's Xvfb session:

```
vncviewer $(docker inspect -f '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' fedora_test_container):0
```

[That last command gets the ip address of the container 'automatically' for use with vncviewer via docker inspect: `docker inspect -f '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' fedora_test_container`]

Those four commands represent what I was hoping to find -- the above seems to be about the minimum to get a clean Fedora environment in docker, sufficient for testing an X application.

One last thing -- if you want to inspect the filesystem or do other testing with the container, you can follow up with this:

```
docker commit fedora_test_container fedora/test_gnofract/001
docker run -it --name=gnofract_test fedora/test_gnofract/001 /bin/bash
```

... and that will give you a root prompt in the container image and you can poke around, or just keep this preserved state of the container so you can quickly 'docker start' it again, and use x11vnc once more to connect and interact with the application.